# Iterating over data frame using chunk without skipping the headder

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I'm trying to iterate over a data frame using chunksize:

```
for i in range(0,number_lines, chunk_size):
    df = pd.read_excel(full_path, nrows=chunk_size, skiprows=i)
```

It would work at the first iteration only but on the rest, it will skip the 1st row (header) and takes a wrong row as a header.

So, I tried to use:

```
for i in range(0,number_lines, chunk_size):
    df = pd.read_excel(full_path, nrows=chunk_size, skiprows = ?, header=None)
```

but in that case, what I should use in `skiprows` in order to always take the 1st row as a header with each iteration?

or there might be another way?

Comment: `skiprows = (1 if i == 0 else 0)` should work i think

Comment: it worked, thanks.
was something like that skiprows=[0 if i == 0 else i for i in range(1,i)